# Restrict acces users and load data from database

Tags: mysql, orbeon

I have two questions:

1) I need restrict the access to orbeon Form and orbeon Runner.
I read the documentation, and this it's possible with the configuration of tomcat, this is real? Any example of this?

2) I need load a data from my database (MySQL) in the dropdown (dynamica or normal) how can I do this?

thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can restrict access to Form Runner using Tomcat. For more on this, see the *container-driven* method, documented in page about [setting up users for access control](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/users.html).
2. You can load data from your database into a dropdown by creating, in Form Builder, a [database service](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/database-services.html), and then an [action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/actions.html) that runs the service, typically on form load, and uses the values returned by the service to populate the dropdown. You'll find more information about this in the pages from the documentation that I linked here.

Comment: thanks @ avernet @avernet I can restrict the acces with your help (Y) . in the second case, i don't see the images... link is broken. So, it's posible load data from XML archive to dropdown o dynamic data dropdown? any example this. Regards!

Comment: @AlejandroGuerrero Here we go: I've updated the [doc on database services](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/database-services.html) and fixed the broken images. And of course, just let us know if you notice any other similar issue.

Comment: thanks @avernet ... Please, do you help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373311/login-and-xml-orbeon

Comment: I'll follow-up on that other post. BTW, there is no need to let me know about other questions you post: I automatically receive a notification about any new post on Stack Overflow with the `orbeon` tag :).