# Login and XML Orbeon

Tags: xml, authentication, jar, tomcat7, orbeon

I have two new questions:

1) I configure the orbeon Form to restrict the access to users (with tomcat). This works good. [But the Page for login is in english (I need view this page in Spanish) and the style from this page is bad.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTzwz.png) So, it's possible configure this page?

I thinked update the orbeon-form-runner.jar, descompress and edit the login.xhtml and compress to new orbeon-form-runner.jar but i recibe a error when i start the orbeon:

this is the error:

```
At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

2.- I try load data from XML to dinamic data dropdown.

I followed the example in the documentation to orbeon, and work this action (Load States).

But i need load in the dropdown my data ¿Where do i start?¿What is the structure from file to load data from XML to DropDown?

PD: I use Tomcat 7 and the orbeon run in Centos 6.5

Answer (score 0):

1. The login page is very much just an example, and admins are expected to customize it, if they wish to use use this method for authenticating users. As you've noted, you can extract that file from a `jar`. Then, instead of putting it back in the `jar`, just place it inside the exploded `war` under `resources/apps/fr/login.xhtml`. This way, you can also change the file without having to restart Tomcat.
2. You service just returns XML, and in Form Builder you use the "choices", "label", and "value" expressions to extract the data from the XML document. For instance: choices as `/states/state`, label as `@name`, and value as `@abbreviation`, per the example on the [page about the dynamic dropdown](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/dynamic-data-dropdown.html).

Comment: thanks avernet... 1) I update jar and compress again .jar ... and run good.. but your advice it's most easy  the previous... Thanks..

Comment: Yes, updating the `jar` is OK too; it's just more time consuming, also because in general you need to restart Tomcat, and since a few commands are needed more error prone. I'm glad you got this to work!